# Unable to get the root ref in Cloud Functions for Firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

There is another way for get the root ref?

```
exports.orderUser = functions.database.ref('/orders/{shopId}/{orderId}').onWrite(event => {
    var eventSnapshot = event.data;
    // ...
    var rootRef = eventSnapshot.ref.parent.parent.parent; <== this line
    var userRef = rootRef.child(`/users/${user}/orders`);
});
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`eventSnapshot.ref.root`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.Reference#root) will give you the root reference.